# I'd like to know what is the issue which cause wrong display in my code?

Tags: c, string, do-while

I'd like to know what's the problem where i want to Write a function which, given a string, return TRUE if all characters are distinct and FALSE if any character is repeated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
char distinct_or_not_string(char *string []);
int main()
{ 
  char str[20];
  char result;
  printf("please entre your string:");
  gets(str);
  printf("\n");
 result=distinct_or_not_string(str);   

}
char distinct_or_not_string(char *string [])
{
    int i=0,j;
    while(string[i]!='\0')
    {
        j=i+1;
        while(string[i]!='\0')
        {
              if(string[i]==string[j])
              {
                  return printf("false");
              }
         j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return printf("true");
}
```

Comment: The second while loop condition is using wrong index. Should be `j` instead of `i`

Comment: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has four issues.

1. You use `gets` to catch the string from `stdin`. Never ever use `gets`. It is deprecated because of security reasons since with that, you could easily run into buffer overflow, when the input string is longer than the buffer itself. `gets` don´t stop scanning.

[Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Use `fgets` instead, which limits the input according to the size of the buffer:

```
fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);
```

---

2. Wrong parameter type of `distinct_or_not_string()`:

```
char distinct_or_not_string(char *string []);
```

`string` is of type `char **` but you want to pass a pointer to a string. Use either `char string[]` or `char *string` where `string` is of type `char *`.

---

3. The second while loop uses the the wrong object to proof the condition, `i` instead of `j`:

```
while(string[i]!='\0')
```

---

4. Use of `printf` as return value of `distinct_or_not_string()`:

```
return printf("false");
```

`printf()` will be always evaluated to `1` (assuming no error has occurred at printing) and thus `result` in the `main` function would always have `1` regardless of the string has any character twice or more or not, which is not appropriate.

Split both and make each statement separate:

```
printf("false");
return 0;
```

and

```
printf("true");
return 1;
```

---

Side note:
`distinct_or_not_string()` does not need to return a `char`; the return value in this case has nothing to do with a string or a character of it.

So the return type of `distinct_or_not_string()` shall, in my opinion, preferable be `int` for better readability and to avoid confusions, although it isn´t a syntactic mistake to use `char` instead. The declaration of the function would then be like that:

```
int distinct_or_not_string(char *string);
```

---

The corrected code should be like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int distinct_or_not_string(char* string);

int main()
{ 
  char str[20];
  int result;

  printf("please enter your string: ");
  char *p = fgets(str,sizeof str,stdin);
  if(p == NULL)
  {
      printf("Error occurred at reading the input!");
      return 1;
  }

  printf("\n");

  result = distinct_or_not_string(str); 
  return 0;  
}

int distinct_or_not_string(char *string)
{
    int i=0,j;
    while(string[i] != '\0')
    {
        j=i+1;
        while(string[j] != '\0')
        {
              if(string[i] == string[j])
              {
                  printf("false");
                  return 0;
              }
         j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("true");
    return 1;
```

If you want to test this code online, here is the link: https://onlinegdb.com/H1PCstoSL

Comment: but in the fourth issue (i want to return the statement which tell user true or false so i never mind what is the actual results of  return  either 0 nor 1           @roberts-supports-monica-cellio

Comment: @sarahamdy I added a bit more, maybe this will help you to understand how it works - if every character is distinct from eah other you use `printf("true")` and return the value 1 and if not, you use `printf("false")` and return the value 0.

Comment: @sarahamdy You can test the code here: https://onlinegdb.com/SJ_tNKiHU

Comment: so you put return 0 , return 1 to distinct between  the two returns i mean in my code the return will be 1 in both (either distinct or not) as i used printf statement in the return statement which always returns 1 so to be more accurate we shouldn't use printf statment in return

Comment: @sarahamdy The problem is when you want to know if every character was distinct or not inside the `main()` function for use it later. Of course, You print out that it is true or false but **if** you would want to use the result of `distinct_or_not_string` anywhere else, you need to know if it was so. `result` in `main` is meant for that and it needs to have the appropriate value in it **if** you want to make anything else in the program based off if the string has distinct characters or not.

Comment: @sarahamdy But if you do not want to do something else later - the program has only this task - you could omit the return value and the `return` object in `main` at all and use the return type of `void`: `void distinct_or_not_string(char *string)` - the type `void` means this function has no valid return value and do not need to have one.

Comment: @sarahamdy Here is the link to  the Wikipedia site about type `void` and what a function with `void` return value is. I recommend you to take a look at this page. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Void_type

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
 char distinct_or_not_string(char *string [])
```

to

```
 char distinct_or_not_string(char string [])
```

and

change this in second while loop

```
while(string[i]!='\0')
```

to

```
while(string[j]!='\0')
```

Answer (score 0):

my mistake is in the second loop where i used the same index i instead of j so the condition is always true so the following code works successfully

```
#include <stdio.h>
char distinct_or_not_string(char string []);
int main()
{ 
  char str[20];
  char result;
  printf("please entre your string:");
  gets(str);
  printf("\n");
 result=distinct_or_not_string(str);   

}
char distinct_or_not_string(char string [])
{
    int i=0,j;
    while(string[i]!='\0')
    {
        j=i+1;
        while(string[j]!='\0')
        {
              if(string[i]==string[j])
              {
                  return printf("false");
              }
         j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return printf("true");
}
```

Comment: But that is not the one and only mistake you made. Look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60691594/12139179).